# How to calculate the tangential of a chart practically?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, differential-geometry

so, I don't understand how one can calculate the tangential of a chart at some point. Let's say that: \

1. $M$ is an $m$-dimensional $C^q$ submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$;
2. $q ∈ N^× ∪{∞}$
3. $p ∈ M$, and $(ϕ,U)$ is a chart of $M$ around $p$;
4. $(g, V)$ is the parametrization belonging to $(ϕ,U)$.

As my textbook defines it, the tangential of a chart is such an isomorphism $A$ that:

\begin{equation}
T_{\phi(p)}g(A) = i_{T_pM}
\end{equation}
where $i_{T_pM}$ is the canonical injection of $T_pM$ into $T_{p}\mathbb{R}^n$. I understand that $T_{\phi(p)}g$ must be invertible, but how do we calculate it in practical terms, so that we can calculate $T_{p}\phi$? I guess my problem is that if we consider $g$ to be a function from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\partial g$ won't be invertible.

Say, we have $M = {(x, y): x^2 + y^2 = 1, \; y > 0}$, and $g(t) = (\cos(t), \sin(t))$ for $t \in (0, \pi)$. How can we calculate $T_{p}\phi$ for some point $p$?

Comment: In my textbook, $T_p f$ is defined as a function from $T_p X$ to $T_p Y$, $(p, v) \to (f(p), \partial f(p) v$. $T_p X$ is the tangential space of $X$ at point $p$, i.e. the set ${p} \times \mathbb{R}^n$. That's why I use $T_p\phi$ and $T_{(\phi(p)} g$.

Comment: No, the tangent space of $X$ at $p$ is *not* $\{p\}\times\Bbb R^n$. It is $\{p\}\times V$ for some $m$-dimensional subspace $V\subset\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: $X$ is not a manifold in the definition above, but simply an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. In particular, tangent space of $X$ at $p$ is ${p} \times \mathbb{R}^n$. My textbook defines tangential space for a manifold later on based on this definition.